# MRUnit: Tests fail with custom writable

Tags: unit-testing, hadoop

I am trying to implement unit test for my hadoop jobs using [MRUnit](http://mrunit.apache.org/).

For my own Writable, the assertions in

```
withOutput(K2 k2, V2 v2)
```

fail. I have tried overriding the equals(Object o) method from Object, but that doesn't help. Any ideas how to tell MRUnit when two Writables are actually the same?

Comment: I have not found out how to get `withOutput` to work, but it instead of running `runTest()`, I am now using `run()`, which returns a List. This way one can use the JUnit assertion methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for `runTest()` to succeed, `int hashCode()` has to be overridden.